# mongo-memory-server/nest process failed to exit gracefully. Likely leak on teardown

Tags: mongodb, jestjs, nestjs, mongo-memory-server

I have Mongoose In memory test helper that I'm using with a controller test:

**Helper**

```
import { MongooseModule, MongooseModuleOptions } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { MongoMemoryServer } from 'mongodb-memory-server';
import { connection } from 'mongoose';

let mongod: MongoMemoryServer;

export const rootMongooseTestModule = (options: MongooseModuleOptions = {}) =>
  MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
    useFactory: async () => {
      mongod = await MongoMemoryServer.create();
      const mongoUri = await mongod.getUri();
      return {
        uri: mongoUri,
        ...options,
      };
    },
  });

export const closeInMongodConnection = async () => {
  connection.dropDatabase();
  connection.close();
  if (mongod) await mongod.stop();
};

export const removeCollections = async () => {
  const collections = connection.collections;
  for (const key in collections) {
    const collection = collections[key];
    await collection.deleteMany({});
  }
}
```

**UserController Test**

```
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import {
  closeInMongodConnection,
  removeCollections,
  rootMongooseTestModule,
} from '../../test/utils/MongooseTestModule';
import { UserSchema } from './user.schema';
import { UserController } from './user.controller';
import { UserService } from './user.service';

describe('UserController', () => {
  let controller: UserController;

  const mockUser = {
    username: 'kyle',
    email: 'kyle@example.com',
    password: 'password',
  };
 
  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      controllers: [UserController],
      imports: [
        rootMongooseTestModule(),
        MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: 'User', schema: UserSchema }]),
      ],
      providers: [UserService],
    }).compile();
    controller = module.get<UserController>(UserController);
  });

  afterAll(async () => {
    await closeInMongodConnection();
  });

  afterEach(async () => {
    await removeCollections();
  });

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(controller).toBeDefined();
  });

  describe('create', () => {
    it('should return the saved object', async () => {
      const createdUser = await controller.create(mockUser);
      expect(createdUser.username).toBe(mockUser.username);
    });
  });

});
```

After the test I close the connection and remove all collections, but for some reason I'm still getting:

`npm test --detectOpenHandles`

tried this too:

`npm test --runInBand --detectOpenHandles`

> A worker process has failed to exit gracefully and has been force exited. This is likely caused by tests leaking due to improper teardown. Try running with --detectOpenHandles to find leaks. Active timers can also cause this, ensure that .unref() was called on them.

The test does finish and doesn't hang:

```
Test Suites: 15 passed, 15 total
Tests:       16 passed, 16 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        5.369 s
```

When I add `await connection.dropDatabase();` in the `closeInMongodConnection` function my tests take about 3 more seconds.

Is there anyway to fix this error? Is this just happening because opening and closing mongo connections is slow? I'm not sure what's going on because it seems like I'm doing everything I'm suppose too

**Edit:**

After un commenting `await connection.dropDatabase();` I'm now getting:

```
thrown: "Exceeded timeout of 5000 ms for a hook.
    Use jest.setTimeout(newTimeout) to increase the timeout value, if this is a long-running test."
```